# Ballot operation in MPI

Tags: c++, ubuntu, mpi, openmpi

In Open MPI 4.0.3, how to implement the operation that is known as Ballot in CUDA?
Each host knows a boolean value (whether it's a GPU or CPU host). I need to get a boolean array on each host containing `a[i]==true` iff `i`-th host is a GPU host. The array must be the same on each host.

The language is C++ (C is fine too) and the OS is Ubuntu 20.04 .

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds like an `MPI_Allgather`
https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Allgather.html